# Google Play Services stops working

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

I am making a Unity game for android. For unknown reasons I first got the DDL exception error only when I was running the game on my phone.
    DllNotFoundException: gpg

After reimporting the Google Plugins from 
[here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)
 I recive this two errors during compilation:

[image]

[image]

I have already tried this :  Asset - Play Services Resolver - Android Resolver - Force Resolve.

The most interesting thing for me is that before it was working perfectly well and i did not changed anything connected to google-play-services at least on purpose.

Comment: It says that the plugin is corrupted. Maybe, a bad download? Delete all the Android plugin folders. Restart Unity. Download them again. Try the build and see what happens.